# winrt backspace in Settingsflyout

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I create simple SettingsFlyout panel following this example of microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx

Everything is fine, but how can I make backspace go back to settings panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can doing what you want if you edit the control. Use Blend will help you so much. Right Click => Edit Template.

Comment: I create my own template, but still I don't find out how make backspace go to settings panel.

Comment: What do you mean when you said backspace?

Comment: Oh wait, when you create normal settings panel, you got backspace, right?

Comment: We are speaking about the backbutton for settingsFlyout? Create new windows store apps.Add settingsFlyout, init your settings flyout in mainPage.xaml.cs and show. It's sur, you got backbutton in your settings flyout

Comment: I create evrything from beginnig and now is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

In code behind

```
  private void settingsAbout_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Back)
        {
            SettingsPane.Show();
        }
    }
```

in xaml

```
KeyDown="settingsAbout_KeyDown"
```